# Is it possible to open chrome inspect element with selenium in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to open the inspect element in a chrome browser for a project I'm working on and I can't figure out if it's no possible or what. If I try and just use F12 like so:

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.send_keys(Keys.F12)
action.perform()
```

Then nothing happens at all. Same results if I try using the full shortcut (Control+Shift+i):

```
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
action.key_down(Keys.SHIFT)
action.send_keys('i')
action.perform()

action.key_up(Keys.SHIFT)
action.key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
action.perform()
```

If I use a different shortcut, such as Control+a to highlight everything on a given page, it works. I've thought about the possibility of somehow right-clicking and then having it click on the inspect button, but I'm unsure how feasible that is. If anyone has any tips at all I'd really appreciate it.

I don't know if I'm just doing something entirely wrong or if maybe it just isn't possible but either way I'd like to get some closure at the least.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can read  [Chrome options](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)! and I think you can use this options like that:

```
chromeOptions = ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```